# Android App works on Eclipse Emulator but Play Store says my device is not compatible

Tags: android, android-emulator, google-play, android-manifest

I'm programmming an App that works fine when I run it on the emulator with Android 2.2, also I execute the .apk in my tablet Galaxy Tab2 Android 4.0.3 and works fine too.

Then, I sign the App and put on the Market like a Beta Version and when I go to install, Play Store says that my tablet is not compatible.

In my AndroidManifest, I define the minSdkVersion = "8" and the targetSdkVersion = "17"

Any suggestions?

Thanks ;)

Edit:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="*myPackage*"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<supports-screens 
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar" >
    <activity
        android:name="*myPackage.MainActivity*"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <MyOtherActivities... />
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: post ur manifest file

Comment: Edited with my AndroidManifest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update  :**

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="true" />
```

[reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10475954/why-does-the-google-play-store-say-my-android-app-is-incompatible-with-my-own-de)  and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8893860/android-why-is-my-app-not-available-for-my-2-3-3-device-in-the-market)

Comment: Actually, my App allows you to take a photo but doesn't should be required. Should I delete these two lines?

Comment: Finally, I solved define the android:required = "false". Thanks very much!! ;)