# Device not supported when installing app from googleplay.

Tags: android, eclipse, google-play, android-manifest

I have opened my app for beta testing on Google Play. I tested the app on my phone **(Samsung Galaxy Y S5360)** using eclipse before uploading it to Google Play. It runs smoothly from eclipse, but when I opened it as beta in Google Play and tried to download the app to my phone. It says **“Your device isn't compatible with this version”**.

Here is my Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.myproject.newapp"
    android:versionCode="10"
    android:versionName="2.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/mc_logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock" >
        <service android:name="com.myproject.newapp.QueueService" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.myproject.newapp.LoginActivity"
            android:icon="@drawable/mc1_logo"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>


        <activity
            android:name="com.myproject.newapp.SplashScreenActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_splashscreen"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity


    </application>

</manifest>
```

As you can see I declared the **minSdkVersion="9"** which matches my phones android version. Im new to uploading android apps in Google Play, please help me out. Thank you very much.

Comment: which version of android in your device (Samsung Galaxy Y S5360)

Comment: go to this so post and cross check [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16787186/android-app-works-on-eclipse-emulator-but-play-store-says-my-device-is-not-compa?rq=1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16787186/android-app-works-on-eclipse-emulator-but-play-store-says-my-device-is-not-compa?rq=1)

Comment: Android API 9. GingerBread 2.3 is the version sir.

Comment: can you able to remove the app from the device and test again

Comment: Yes sir. I tried several times to uninstall and upload the app again on Play Store but still no use.

Comment: no idea what is happening, please try with  android:minSdkVersion="8", some times it help

Comment: if you can, clear the goole play data from setting, it not work  factory rest your phone

Comment: Changing the api level to 8 did not work. Play Store Console still shows my phone under the unsupported device list.

Comment: @SimplePlan Thank you so much. adding this line worked.              <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="false" />

Comment: @icaneatclouds yo welcome!